# how can we print the error/success message from session object "lastAddedMessage" in magento

Tags: magento

I have print the SESSION on customer login page, i want to know that how can i print the error/success message from session object in magento

> lastAddedMessage

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass your message from some controller action before redirecting to some url and it will be displayed when page will be landed

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess('My Message');
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError('My Message');
$this->_redirect('customer/account/index');
```

OR

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('My Message');
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('My Message');
$this->_redirect('mymodule/mycontroller/myaction');
```